# How to transition to a ViewController from a xib by push

Tags: ios, swift3, xcode8

How to transition to a ViewController from a xib by push?

I know how to do it by modal, but I could not find any information of it by push.

Do you have any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can't call performSegueWithIdentifier in a Xib class, only in a UIViewController class.

Create a delegate in Xib class and UIViewController class implements that delegate protocol.